# How to allow throttle only if the response was successful?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, twilio-api, throttling

I'm trying to make throttling on OTP authentication so user can only send one message every minute

```
class BurstRateThrottle(AnonRateThrottle, UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'burst'
```

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
    ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'burst': '1/min',
        'anon': '200/min',
        'user': '250/min',
    },
```

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@throttle_classes([BurstRateThrottle])
def login_send_token(request):
    ...
```

The problem with this is that the api gets throttled even when the phone number is wrong so I'm trying to only throttle when the OTP message is send or when the response is 200 or 201

Is there any way to access the response status code in `allow_request` method?
or to manually execute the throttle from the function that call twilio api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by converting `login_send_token` to a class based view

```
class LoginSendToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    throttle_classes = [BurstRateThrottle]
```

after that I overrode `initial` method and commented out the `self.check_throttles(request)` calling

```
    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Runs anything that needs to occur prior to calling the method handler.
        """
        self.format_kwarg = self.get_format_suffix(**kwargs)

        # Perform content negotiation and store the accepted info on the request
        neg = self.perform_content_negotiation(request)
        request.accepted_renderer, request.accepted_media_type = neg

        # Determine the API version, if versioning is in use.
        version, scheme = self.determine_version(request, *args, **kwargs)
        request.version, request.versioning_scheme = version, scheme

        # Ensure that the incoming request is permitted
        self.perform_authentication(request)
        self.check_permissions(request)
        # self.check_throttles(request)
```

and called `check_throttles` from my `post` method after serializer validation
now it only checks throttling if the serializer was valid

Answer (score 0):

The `allow_request` method is run before the method, so you only have the result of the API request after the framework decides whether the request can be run or not.

One way to do this might be to make the request to the API within the `allow_request` method and only add the request to the history of requests if the API request succeeded.

That does mix up where you would expect to find that code though, so an alternative would be to build the custom throttling directly into your `login_send_token` method.